# Seria interessante diretivas usando http.get?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Este é um pedaço do html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="projeto in projetos">
    <td>{{projeto.name}}</td>
    <td>{{projeto.status}}</td>
  </tr>
```

O mesmo utiliza um controller que faz a seguinte função

```
$http.get('system/project/listProjectsPerUser')
.then(function (response){
    if(response.data.success){
        $scope.projetos = response.data.projects;
        console.log($scope.projetos);
    }
    else{
        console.log('Erro');
    }
});
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, se seria interessante colocar esse html como diretiva e utilizar a própria diretiva para realizar a mesma função do controller, de preencher o array **projetos** e exibir o html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai depender do seu contexto, mas de modo geral, não, pois toda vez que a diretiva for renderizada, ela irá executar a chamada `$http`. Muitas vezes a informação não muda constantemente de modo que precisamos toda hora refazer a chamada. Mas se for o caso de necessitar atualizar em u intervalo de tempo curto, ainda assim esse é o trabalho de um `service`, não de u  `controller`, `directive` ou `component`.

Primeiramente, o ideal seria usar `component` ao invés de `directive` para seguir os novos padrões de Angular (2, 3, 4...). Depois, você deve executar as chamadas `$http` e, posteriormente, armazenar as informações em um `service`. Depois, em seu `component` você apenas solicita os dados ao service e exibe.

Deste modo, o seu `component` pode tranquilamente ter o HTML internamente.